# How can I correctly instantiate with __new__ and class methods?

Tags: python, singleton

I have a class, which connects to a server through a python module. The login takes some time, so the idea was to put its instance into a singleton pattern, so I always pass around the exact same instance. In another [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/448082/how-can-i-nicely-pass-on-a-class-instance-in-python) I wrote about the details.

However, I added the `__new__` method to my class as seen below, and after an error which said I provided 4 positional arguments instead of 1 I added `user, pass, url` to the `__new__` function, however this of course doesn't do anything yet. So at this point I am massively confused, how I need to rewrite my init/classmethods/`__new__` to get the same instantiation as before, with the only difference, that I only instantiate once. Also I had the feeling, that `__init__` gets executed every time nevertheless? So is there a way to just shift the content of my `__init__` to `__new__`? Main concern is, how do I assign a variable to the instance which is about to be created? Grateful for any pointers in the right direction!

```py
from pybis import Openbis

class OpenBisLoad:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(OpenBisLoad, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self, username: str, password: str, url: str):
        openbis_object = Openbis(url)
        openbis_object.login(username, password, save_token=True)
        self.openbis_object = openbis_object

    @classmethod
    def login_with_credentials(cls, username: str, password: str):
        url = URL
        return cls(username, password, url)

    @classmethod
    def login_with_env(cls):
        load_dotenv()
        return cls(os.getenv("USER"), os.getenv("PASSWORD"), os.getenv("URL"))
```

Comment: Not the best idea to put such a heavy code into instantiation logic. I would rather use factory @classmethod to track instances and put the login process inside, and then pass `openbis_object` into `__init__` method to keep the object clean.

Answer (score 1):

Jan!

Since the `__init___` method is executed every time you create a new instance of a class and are responsible for initializing the instance attributes and performing any necessary configuration when a new object is created I think your code `__init___` was actually executed each since a new instance was created by generating a different Singleton port. I believe that to implement an appropriate Singleton pattern, you must move the initialization code from `__init___` to `__new___` as seen below:

```
...
    def __new__(cls, username, password, url):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(OpenBisLoad, cls).__new__(cls)
            openbis_object = Openbis(url)
            openbis_object.login(username, password, save_token=True)
            cls._instance.openbis_object = openbis_object
        return cls._instance
...
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this as soon as I get back to work :) thinking about it, cls._instance.openbis_object seems quite obvious.